# Determining if being passed a temporary

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a class `C`, and a function `make_c(x)` which creates instances of C.

`C` stores `x` by reference.

How can I write `make_c(x)` to give a compile error when `x` is an unnamed temporary (that would of course destruct at the end of line, leaving a dangling reference) but accept named temporaries and other values?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I mean with `const T& x = f()`, `x` is a named temporary (it doesn't get destroyed at the end of the line).

Comment: @Clinton: That doesn't destroy at the end of the line. It gets destroyed when `x` goes out of scope.

Comment: @Clinton then it's not temporary.

Comment: @Nawaz: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I think you've been told this before but I'll say it again: it's generally bad to store references in classes.

Comment: @Seth: I agree. I need to identify unnamed temporaries. Perhaps my terminology is wrong. What you you call: f(), const T& x = f(), const T x = f()? I need my function only to reject f().

Comment: Is `x` a known type or is it an inferred template argument?

Comment: @ildjarm: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm happy for `make_c(x)` to be a template function.

Comment: @Clinton: there can be nothing you're doing (nothing that's legal C++, at any rate) that requires that you "identify unnamed temporaries". Indeed, the C++0x language makes it virtually impossible for you to do so, and there's likely a very good reason why they went through the trouble to prevent it.

Comment: @Nicol: Isn't telling rvalues (unnamed temporaries) and lvalues (named things) apart the main reason rvalue references were invented? - Also, identifying temporaries, so as not to store their address seems a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: @UncleBens: No. Rvalues are _not_ just unnamed temporaries. The C++0x specification has rewritten how those things are defined, and they did so for good reasons. Further, why would you be storing the address of a _reference_ you were given in the first place, r-value or not?

Comment: @Nicol: Not the address of a *reference* but whatever is referred to. Because sometimes things need to refer to other things? What's so strange about it?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should have the semantics you're looking for:

```
template<typename X>
C make_c(X&& x)
{
    static_assert(
        !std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(std::forward<X>(x))>::value,
        "x must not be a temporary"
    );
    return C(std::forward<X>(x));
}
```

Caveat: this won't work as-is with VC++ 2010 due to deficiencies in its implementation of `decltype` (you'd need to wrap `decltype` in [`std::identity<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391705.aspx)).

Comment: Could you add some explanation about what the various parts are doing here?  Especially the need for `std::forward<X>` and the need for the explicit `X` in same?  (Sometimes I think all the C++0x "rvalue reference" stuff will never make sense to me.)

Comment: @ildjarn: Does this work in the case `T&& x = f()` (which presumably also extends the lifetime of f(), so should be accepted)?

Comment: @Nemo: Look up questions here on "perfect forwarding".

Comment: @Nemo : Explaining the rules of rvalue reference collapsing is well beyond the scope of this question. If you find them confusing, that may well warrant a proper question on the subject asking for an in-depth answer. :-]

Comment: @Clinton : First, yes, `T&& x = f();` extends the lifetime of the temporary returned by `f()` (see §8.5.3/5 and §12.2/5). Second, no, this code does not work in that case (and I don't think it's ever possible to distinguish between the two, much like it was impossible to distinguish between a `const&` temporary and a `const&` non-temporary in C++03); however, I personally expect that most code taking advantage of "the most important `const`" will be using `const` lvalue references, as that's a fairly well-understood and established practice compared to any idiom relating to rvalue references.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible within the language, because you'd need to check the flow control through arbitrary functions.

```
struct Foo{
};

Foo const & sanitize(Foo const & f){ return f;}

void checkThisFunction(Foo const & f){
   //we'd like to ensure at compile time that f is not a temporary
}

int main(){
   Foo f;
   checkThisFunction(sanitize(f));
   checkThisFunction(sanitize(Foo()));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: So does that code sample work or not? It's not clear (to me) from your answer.

Comment: That is an example of code that works in C++, but there's no way to check that the Foo passed to `checkThisFunction` is not temporary.

Comment: @Ken: I'm happy for both `checkThisFunction(sanitize(f))` and `checkThisFunction(sanitize(Foo()))` to be rejected. I just want `checkThisFunction(f)` to be accepted, and `const Foo& f = Foo(),  checkThisFunction(f)`.

Comment: @Clinton: He very clearly said that you _cannot_ tell the difference. You cannot preferentially filter those possibilities out, with any combination of r-value references and const-l-value references. If `checkThisFunction(f)` works, then `checkThisFunction(sanitize(f))` _must_ also work.

Comment: @Nicol: But he could possibly write a GCC plugin (or Dehydra or TreeHydra plugin) to perform a lint-like check on this particular function. But I don't know much about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding rvalue references, this sort of thing should be doable with simple overloading.

```
void foo(int&&) = delete;
void foo(const int&) { }

int main()
{
   int a;
   foo(a);
   foo(42);  //error, prefers binding to the deleted overload
}
```